# Why $ \bigcup_{a \in J} A_a \subseteq \bigcup_{a \in I} A_a\ $ but $ \bigcap_{a \in J} A_a \not\subseteq \bigcap_{a \in I} A_a\ $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a little confused since this is true
$$
 \bigcup_{a \in J} A_a \subseteq \bigcup_{a \in I} A_a\
$$
And this is false
$$
\bigcap_{a \in J} A_a \subseteq \bigcap_{a \in I} A_a\
$$

If $ J \neq \emptyset \quad \text{and} \quad J \subseteq I \quad 
$

My reasoning is as follows:

Supose $A_\alpha = \{\alpha, 0\}, \quad I = \mathbb{R}, \quad J = \mathbb{N}$

In this case both conditions are true $ \mathbb{N} \subseteq\mathbb{R}\ $ and $J \neq \emptyset$
And in this case
$$
 \bigcup_{a \in J} A_a \subseteq \bigcup_{a \in I} A_a\
$$
And this is also true
$$
\bigcap_{a \in J} A_a \subseteq \bigcap_{a \in I} A_a\
$$

being the last one $ \{\{0\}\} \subseteq \ \{\{0\}\}$ which follows that each set is a subset in itself.

And I can't imagine any other condition of $A_\alpha$ where it's true that

$$
\bigcap_{a \in J} A_a \not\subseteq \bigcap_{a \in I} A_a\
$$

my book says this last one form is correct, I just want to know why?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but if $J \subseteq I$, then 
$$
\bigcap_{a \in J} A_a \supseteq \bigcap_{a \in I} A_a.
$$

Comment: As intuition, union of more groups make your group larger, and intersection of more groups make your group smaller. As a simple counter-example you can take $A = \{1,2\} , B = \{2,3\}, C=\{1,3\}$. We then have $A \cap B = \{ 2 \}$ but $A \cap B \cap C = \varnothing$.

Comment: @Amit: I recommend `\varnothing` for an empty set: $\varnothing$.

Comment: @Sammy Black Thanks :)

Comment: @Alexis What book are you reading?

Comment: By the way, in your example, $\bigcap_{a \in J} A_a \subseteq \bigcap_{a \in I} A_a$ should be $\{0\}\subseteq \{0\}$. $\{0\}$ and $\{\{0\}\}$ are totally different.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. @KartikPandey "Book of proof" Richard Hammack

Answer (score 2):

If $J=\{1\}$ and $I=\{1,2\}$ then generally
$$
\bigcap_{a \in J} A_a =A_1\supsetneqq A_1\cap A_2= \bigcap_{a \in I} A_a.
$$

Consider for instance some $A_1\ne\varnothing$, and $A_2:=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

$A_1=\{1,2\}$, $A_2=\{1,2\}$, $A_3=\{3,2\}$

$J=\{1,2\}$, $I=\{1,2,3\}$

$$
\bigcap_{a \in J} A_a =\{1,2\}\not\subseteq\{2\}= \bigcap_{a \in I} A_a\
$$